# Using "?" operator to check if a string is not null or empty

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Guess I got this code,

```
string a, b;
b = null;
```

How can I use "?" operator to check if b is not null or empty.

**I want to get value of "b" if it's not null or empty in "a"**

I don't want to use, string.IsNullOrEmpty(), Reason --->  I don't want to use "if and else" :)

Let me guess your next question, why don't want to use if and else.

Comment: `var res = b==null?"null":"not null";`

Comment: Why you don't want to use IsNullOrEmpty if it is not a secret? Anything wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard string.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Comment: Don't bother - if that's the code you've got, then b __is__ null and you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: @AlexeyRaga It sounds to me like it might be an interview question.

Comment: _"Let me guess your next question, why don't want to use if and else"_ Why don't you want to use if and else?

Comment: And further, what on earth is wrong with `if`/`else`?

Comment: And more to the point if you don't want to use if and else then why not say that rather than saying you don't want to use `IsNullOrEmpty`?

Comment: @Chris [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Chris because I didn't knew we can...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would work:

```
a = (b ?? "") == "" ? a : b;
```

But why on earth not just use this:

```
a = string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? a : b;
```

There's no need to resort to `if` and `else` with this...

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
a = b == null || b == string.Empty ? "Some Value" : b;
```

Of course, you can always just do this:

```
a = string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? "Some Value" : b;
```

Using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` does not mean you *have* to use a `if` / `else`-block

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you are looking for : `a = (b == null || b.Length < 1 ? a : b);` ?

Comment: need to check for string being empty too.

Comment: @Chris didn't see that :p